# Why do I get the Error "Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: COM is not supported"

Tags: c#, .net

I try get the text from a Word document, but it will always show me the error. I am using .Net 7.0 and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word API.

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;


static string GetTextFromWord()
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object path = @"D:\Articles2.docx";
    object readOnly = true;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

    for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
    {
        text.Append(" \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
    return text.ToString();
}

GetTextFromWord();
```

I tried different methods but it will always show me the same error.

Comment: Try changing the target framework in `csproj` to `net7.0-windows` from `net7.0`. .NET 7 is the cross-platform runtime. COM only works on Windows

Comment: Thanks. Okay I will have to find another way cause I'm coding on a Mac. :)

Comment: In that case the question you should ask first is `How can I automate Word on Mac from a third application?`. Is the feature there in the first place? If it is, it won't be through COM Automation